# Retrieving Arraylist of POJO in a parent POJO, from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been struggling to retrieve data from firebase in my Android Application, I fail to understand how would I retrieve a node which has multiple child nodes.

The situation is that I have a node in firebase **'snaps'** which has a child node **'likes'**. The 'snaps' node is created when a user uploads a photo and 'likes' node is created when a user likes a photo. Each time the photo is liked, a 'liked-by' key-value pair is pushed to **snaps' likes** node.

**Objective:**
To retreive a snap and all its child Likes using POJOs

**My failed attempt to retrieve:**

```
        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL+"snaps/");
    Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("timestamp");

    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {

            Snap snap = snapshot.getValue(Snap.class);
            snapsList.add(snap);

        }


    });
```

**Data heirachy**
[image]

The second snap doesn't contains **likes** nodes because it hasn't been liked yet.

**Snaps' POJO**

```
public class Snap {
private String uid="";
private String uname="";
private String timestamp="";
private String pname="";
private String place="";
private String image="";
private String desc="";
private String likes="";

public Snap() {
}

public Snap(String uid, String uname, String timestamp, String pname, String place, String image, String desc) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.uname = uname;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.pname = pname;
    this.place = place;
    this.image = image;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}

public void setPname(String pname) {
    this.pname = pname;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
}
```

**Data representation- JSON **

```
{
              "snaps" : {
                "-KDJ0yinIYo-gKpVp13w" : {
                  "desc" : "a",
                  "image" : "...",
                  "likes" : {
                    "-KDJ11Bbbc_d1S2hU2Zk" : {
                      "liked_by" : "b64ff43c-7b51-40d1-aac8-6e7c700113e2"
                    }
                  },
                  "place" : "a",
                  "pname" : "a",
                  "timestamp" : "1458477456134",
                  "uid" : "b64ff43c-7b51-40d1-aac8-6e7c700113e2",
                  "uname" : "Dead Man"
                },
                "-KDJ19tOlJ8-W28k5YAD" : {
                  "desc" : "b",
                  "image" : "...",
                  "place" : "b",
                  "pname" : "b",
                  "timestamp" : "1458477506628",
                  "uid" : "b64ff43c-7b51-40d1-aac8-6e7c700113e2",
                  "uname" : "Dead Man"
                }
              },
              "users" : {
                "b64ff43c-7b51-40d1-aac8-6e7c700113e2" : {
                  "email" : "a@a.com",
                  "full_name" : "Dead Man",
                  "image" : "...",
                  "provider" : "password"
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: Please update your question with a text version of your Firebase structure instead of a picture. You can get the text by using the Export button on your Firebase dashboard. Having text in your question makes it searchable as well as keeps us from having to retype it when answering.

Comment: A couple of things:  your snaps node has child nodes of /id, not a /likes node so the structure multiple children with the structure:  /snaps/id/likes. The second thing is that retrieving a node will always retrieve all of the children within the node, so it's not clear what you are asking; do you want to retrieve all of the nodes within /snaps? or a specific one? You can probably find the answer  here [Firebase Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) or at least help to refine the question.

Comment: @Jay, I added the json and yes I intend to retrieve all the nodes within /snaps but I cant figure how the POJO should be.

Comment: You can't directly do that. There isn't a way to retrieve just the /likes node for each /id child node. You can however, retrieve each /id node and then evaluate the data in the /likes node. The structure is always key:value pairs, and the value could be another set of key:value pairs. So once you read in the /id node, grab the value of the /likes node and iterate over it to get the data you need. If you have not done so already, going through the example provided in the link in my my prior comment will really help.

Comment: Note that, you could directly access each /liked node if you knew the specific path to it, but I don't think that's the scope of this question.

Comment: @Jay, I understand that the Firebase docs are extensive to help out on this issue but main problem is that when I try to fetch /snaps , all its children are also fetched including ids of likes which my POJO has no idea of and the application crashes.

Comment: Define a Likes class with the needed structure and then in your Snaps class, instead of private String likes=""; try private Likes likes;.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a Likes class with the needed structure and then in your Snaps class, instead of private String likes=""; try private Likes likes;

Something like:

```
public class Snap
    {
      private Likes likes;

      public Likes getLikes ()
        {
            return likes;
        }

        public void setLikes (Likes likes)
        {
            this.likes = likes;
        }
    {
```

and add a class for each of the children of likes as well, using the same format.